# Route in rails is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i have used devise gem for authentication.in same project i have used album model. but my new_user_album_path is giving error.i think there is user id problem.please help me.

this is index.html.erb file

```
<%= link_to 'New Article', new_user_album_path() %>
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
 </tr>

  <% @albums.each do |album| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= album.title %></td>
    <td><%= album.description %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_album_path(album.user,album) %></td>
 <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_album_path(album.user,album) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'destroy', user_album_path(album.user,album),
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>

   <% end %>
   </table>



     this is albums_controller file

   class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
    @albums = current_user.albums.all

       end

        def show
         @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
       end

    def new
    @album = current_user.albums.new
   end

    def edit
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    end

   def create

   @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)
   if @album.save
   redirect_to action: 'index'
   else
      render 'new'
   end
  end

     def update
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])

      if @album.update(album_params)
      redirect_to action: 'show'
      else
      render 'edit'
      end
     end

     def destroy
      @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
      @album.destroy
     redirect_to action: 'index'
     end
    private
    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
    end

   end

   it is giving following errror.->


       NoMethodError in Albums#index



    undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass

    Extracted source (around line #2):

       <h1>Your Albums</h1>
    <%= link_to 'New Article', new_user_album_path(@album.users.id) %>
       <table>
       <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>

route.rb file

    devise_for :users
   # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created priority.
 # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   resources :users do
   resources :albums
   end

   root 'albums#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the routes are set up correctly, then the following should be the problem:

```
new_user_album_path()
```

requests a path for a nested resource, and need to get the parent object, which is your user:

```
new_user_album_path(user_id: current_user.id)
```

I think even this works:

```
new_user_album_path(current_user)
```

If this does not work, 
You should check that the routes are like you think they are by calling from the shell

```
rake routes
```

Look for the `new_user_album_path` in the output:

- Is it really there?
- Are singular and plural the same for all name parts?
- What parameters does it need?

Comment: (user_id: current_user.id)

Comment: <%= form_for @album, as: :album, url: albums_path do |f| %> is not working

Comment: you can thank me (and other stackoverflow users that helped you) by upvoting the answer(s) that helped you. If the problem is solved, you can "accept" an answer, then other users see the the problem is no longer open for you.

Answer (score 0):

Other stuff may be incorrect, but in your `albums#index` you defined the variable `@albums`, but in your In your link you used `@album`

Update

`<%= link_to("New Article, new_user_album_path(@album.users.id)`

to

`<%= link_to("New Article, new_user_album_path(@albums.users.id)`

To receive a different error. A little more explanation on your objectives would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change to:

```
<%= link_to 'New Article', new_user_album_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: undefined method `user' for #<Album::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x000000033ddaf8>

Comment: yes, @albums is a "relation" or a list of albums. the list has no user attribute, only the singular album